# Binning with zero values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of 633 values, ~50% of which are 0. Ideally, I'd like to bin my values (for choropleth mapping purposes) using `qcut()`, but that gives me an error due to non-unique bin edges.
What's the best way to separate the data, quantile the non-zero values, and then recombine them into a single column such that zero values have a value of 0, and quantiled values have `categorical.label + 1`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you replace your zero values with `NaN`, `cut()` and `qcut()` behave as expected; those rows will have a bin value (from `Categorical.labels`) of `-1`:

```
df['density'].replace(to_replace=0, value=np.nan, inplace=True)
```