# Bin all values of a dataframe into percentiles in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, bins

I have a dataframe with all numeric columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1001)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
```

I want to create common quantiles which includes all values of `A` and `B`. There are some missing values in both. Once the common quantiles are created I want to encode values in the dataframe to show labels according to what quantile the values fall within. I can do it column wise for every column but how can I do it over a dataframe?

Comment: You could apply your column-wise logic to `df.stack()`, then unstack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can first [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) `DataFrame`, use [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1001)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df.ix[0,'A'] = np.nan
df.ix[2,'A'] = np.nan
df.ix[3,'B'] = np.nan
print (df)
          A         B
0       NaN -0.896065
1 -0.306299 -1.339934
2       NaN -0.641727
3  1.307946       NaN
4  0.829115 -0.023299
5 -0.208564 -0.916620
6 -1.074743 -0.086143
7  1.175839 -1.635092
8  1.228194  1.076386
9  0.394773 -0.387701

bins = np.linspace(-1, 1, 5)
print (pd.qcut(df.stack(), bins).unstack())
                  A                 B
0               NaN  (-1.635, -0.209]
1  (-1.635, -0.209]  [-1.34, -0.0861]
2               NaN  (-1.635, -0.209]
3   (-0.209, 1.308]               NaN
4   (-0.209, 1.308]   (-0.209, 1.308]
5  (-1.635, -0.209]  (-1.635, -0.209]
6  (-1.635, -0.209]   (-0.209, 1.308]
7   (-0.209, 1.308]               NaN
8   (-0.209, 1.308]   (-0.209, 1.308]
9   (-0.209, 1.308]  (-1.635, -0.209]
```

Comment: My datapoints are a little different and I am getting an error:- Bin edges must be unique: array([   0.        ,    0.        ,    0.66666667,    1.6       ,  112.        ]) Anyway I just needed to change the percentile values to get different bin edges.

Comment: I think one posible solution is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36883735/2901002).