# pd.qcut with values that are inf (infinity) ValueError: Bin edges must be unique:

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I have a data set that is a ratio of 2 float type numbers. Some values have `inf` for infinity (divide by zero) situation.  How do I work with `pd.qcut/pd.cut` with `inf` values?

My data can be accessed [here](http://pastebin.com/q9NZajRM).

```
q = pd.qcut(df['ratio'], 10)

ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([  1.20089207e+03,   6.02984295e+04,   1.26445577e+05,
         2.29982770e+05,   5.13176079e+05,   1.28794976e+06,
         4.96001538e+06,              nan,              nan,
                    nan,              inf])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could `replace` the `np.inf` with `np.nan` then `dropna`

```
q = pd.qcut(df.ratio.replace(np.inf, np.nan).dropna(), 10)
```

Comment: This is great. However, I don't want to drop na. Is there a way to just ignore them in the qcut? Alternatively, since a inf is a very high number, ideally they should be assigned the highest bin. Is something like this possible?

Comment: What I did was to a value of 10 for all index locations where the ratio was inf. So this works.