# Pandas qcut "ValueError: Bin edges must be unique"

Tags: python, pandas, discretization

Yes I know there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639189/pandas-qcut-error-valueerror-bin-edges-must-be-unique) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475398/pd-qcut-valueerror-bin-edges-must-be-unique) [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309144/qcut-pandas-valueerror-bin-edges-must-be-unique) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880490/why-use-pandas-qcut-return-valueerror-bin-edges-must-be-unique).

This question is about a specific behavior:

```
import pandas as pd
x = [
    0,0,0,0,
    1,1,1,
    2,2,2,
    3,3,3
]

print pd.qcut(x, 4)
# ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3]).
```

I had assumed `qcut` would produce edges `(0,1], (1,2], (2,3], (3, 3)`, which would bin the items how I visually organized them. This obviously has to something to do with left-inclusivity and right-exclusivity but intuitively it feels like `x` can be discretized into four parts.

Does anyone have a sense of what I'm missing?