# Python ValueError: Bin edges must be unique

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, bin

Working in python with pandas, I am trying to assign control and treatment groups to different groups of customers.

I have a large dataset. Instead of giving an example of the data, let me show you the pivot, since this summarizes the most important data.

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Test Group'],values=["Customer_ID"],aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))
```

I get those counts
Test Group   Customer_ID

```
Innovators 4634
Early Adopters 2622
Early Majority 8653
Late Majority 7645
Laggards 7645
Lost 4354
Prospective 653
```

I run the following code:

```
percentages = {'Innovators':[0.0,1.0],\
     'Early Adopters':[0.2,0.8], \
     'Early Majority':[0.1,0.9],\
     'Late Majority':[0.0,1.0],\
     'Laggards':[0.2,0.8],\
     'Lost':[0.1,0.9],\
     'Prospective':[0.1,0.9]}

def assigner(gp):
     ...:     group = gp['Test Group'].iloc[0]
     ...:     cut = pd.qcut(
                  np.arange(gp.shape[0]), 
                  q=np.cumsum([0] + percentages[group]), 
                  labels=range(len(percentages[group]))
              ).get_values()
     ...:     return pd.Series(cut[np.random.permutation(gp.shape[0])], index=gp.index, name='flag')

df['flag'] = df.groupby('Test Group', group_keys=False).apply(assigner)

ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([   0,    0, 2621], dtype=int64).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg
```

... and keep on getting this error

I found this answer, which could be helpful [How to qcut with non unique bin edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158597/how-to-qcut-with-non-unique-bin-edges/40548606#40548606) ; but rank dowsn't work for np

```
def assigner(gp):
     ...:     group = gp['Campaign Test Description'].iloc[0]
     ...:     cut = pd.qcut(
                  np.arange(gp.shape[0]).rank(method='first'), 
                  q=np.cumsum([0] + percentages[group]), 
                  labels=range(len(percentages[group]))
              ).get_values()
     ...:     return pd.Series(cut[np.random.permutation(gp.shape[0])], index=gp.index, name='flag')

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rank'
```

I tried dropping duplicates

```
def assigner(gp):
     ...:     group = gp['Campaign Test Description'].iloc[0]
     ...:     cut = pd.qcut(
                  np.arange(gp.shape[0]), 
                  q=np.cumsum([0] + percentages[group]), 
                  labels=range(len(percentages[group])),duplicates='drop'
              ).get_values()
     ...:     return pd.Series(cut[np.random.permutation(gp.shape[0])], index=gp.index, name='flag')

ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges
```

Still getting an error

Comment: What does the output look like? Just different splits for each Customer_ID (100:0. 80:20 etc). Perhaps assign a random number between 0 and 1 for every row, and then use cut-offs based on Customer_ID to get test flag.

Comment: yes, that's what the output looks like; but should qcut do that for me?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with that method but here is how I would tackle the problem:
`df_pct = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID': ['Innovators','Early Adopters' ,'Early Majority','Late Majority','Laggards','Lost','Prospective'], 'test_cutoff':[1,0.8,0.9,0.1,0.8,0.9,0.9]})` `df=df.merge(df_pct)`
`df['is_test'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) >= df['test_cutoff']`

Comment: do you mind posting this as an answer? If it works, I will upvote and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a train/test split, which is commonly used in machine learning. Here is a way to do it (double check that I have your percentages the right way around):

`df_pct = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID': ['Innovators','Early Adopters' ,'Early Majority','Late Majority','Laggards','Lost','Prospective'], 'test_cutoff':[1,0.8,0.9,0.1,0.8,0.9,0.9]})
df=df.merge(df_pct)
df['is_test'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) >= df['test_cutoff']`

Also, your 'Late Majority' percentages don't add up to 100.

Comment: typo, it was supposed to be 1.0 and not 0.1

Comment: this actually worked, let me test it further if the cutoffs are correct and I will accept it, thank you

Comment: Don't sound so surprised! By the way, I found that simple train/test split from [here](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/trees_and_forests/random_forest_classifier_example/) a while ago. It seems to have been updated recently.

You can use something like `df.groupby(['ID', 'is_test']).size()` to make sure the IDs are being grouped as you expect.

Comment: sorry! it's just that np generally doesnt split exactly

Comment: yeah, the cutoffs arent exact, but it works and its far cleaner

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Don't forget to set `random.seed()` if you want to repeat your group classification exactly, otherwise if you rerun the code, you will end up with a slightly different group classification due to the random numbers.