# Need uniform tied rankings for a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to Pandas. I have a DataFrame like below:

```
In [47]: print(d1)
         date name            sector     value
0  2014-10-31    A  Information Tech  -3.18229
1  2014-10-31    B       Industrials  -52.1333
2  2014-10-31    C  Consumer Discret   45.3428
3  2014-10-31    D       Industrials   -4.4901
4  2014-10-31    E       Industrials   6.85653
5  2014-10-31    F  Information Tech   4.56422
6  2014-10-31    H  Information Tech  29.31419
7  2014-10-31    G  Information Tech   6.52422
8  2014-10-31    I            Sports  16.52422
9  2014-10-31    J            Sports   2.62176
```

Use-case is, for a particular day of records, I need uniform ranking for the **value** column. Rank should always lie between **1 to 6** irrespective of the number of records. In case of a tie, I need to give an average of the rank for those records.

For simplicity, I've kept the total_rows as just 10 above, in reality, it is a much higher number for every date(in range of thousands). And the range of ranks would be from **1 to 100**

`Output can be something like below:`

```
         date name            sector     value  rank
0  2014-10-31    A  Information Tech  -3.18229  5
1  2014-10-31    B       Industrials  -52.1333  6
2  2014-10-31    C  Consumer Discret   45.3428  1
3  2014-10-31    D       Industrials   -4.4901  5
4  2014-10-31    E       Industrials   6.85653  3
5  2014-10-31    F  Information Tech   4.56422  3
6  2014-10-31    H  Information Tech  29.31419  1
7  2014-10-31    G  Information Tech   6.52422  3
8  2014-10-31    I            Sports  16.52422  2
9  2014-10-31    J            Sports   2.62176  4
```

What is the best way to provide uniform ranks? I tried to search a lot, could not find anything useful.

Comment: is rank going to be random number or some function of `value`?

Comment: Rank should always fall between 1 to 6 in case of the DF I shared above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to find the apt solution for my use-case. 
I use `cut` functions with pandas `rank` function.

```
df['rank'] = pd.cut(df['value'], 100, labels = list(range(1,101)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `pd.qcut`:

```
df['rank'] = pd.qcut(df['value'], 6, [*'654321'])
```

Or

```
df['rank'] = pd.qcut(df['value'], 6, labels = ['6','5','4','3','2','1'])
```

Output:

```
             date name            sector     value rank
0 2014-10-31         A  Information Tech  -3.18229    5
1 2014-10-31         B       Industrials -52.13330    6
2 2014-10-31         C  Consumer Discret  45.34280    1
3 2014-10-31         D       Industrials  -4.49010    6
4 2014-10-31         E       Industrials   6.85653    3
5 2014-10-31         F  Information Tech   4.56422    4
6 2014-10-31         H  Information Tech  29.31419    1
7 2014-10-31         G  Information Tech   6.52422    3
8 2014-10-31         I            Sports  16.52422    2
9 2014-10-31         J            Sports   2.62176    5
```

Comment: Your command is failing due to Syntax error at '*'. So, I removed it. Then it fails saying, `Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges`

Comment: I am using unpacking here, this may be a version issue, replace [*'654321'] with ['6','5','4',3','2','1']. `pd.qcut(df['value'], 6, labels = ['6','5','4','3','2','1'])`

Comment: yes, looked like a difference in the version. I am using pandas 0.23.4

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.2

Comment: Strange. The first syntax should work.  Nonetheless, does the second syntax work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181590/discussion-between-mayank-porwal-and-scott-boston).

Comment: I digged in a bit deeper. So, `qcut` fails if there are duplicate values. I took help from @luca 's answer in the following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158597/how-to-qcut-with-non-unique-bin-edges
Now, everything works. Thanks.