# How to automatically decide the max number of quantiles when using qcut given a number in pandas?

Tags: pandas

Goal: I want to find cut values with max equal bins using `qcut` given a `q` value. But I have to try one by one to find it. Here is the details:

```
max_bin = 12

pd.qcut([0,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7],q=max_bin)
```

It would raised `ValueError: Bin edges must be unique`.Then I try `11` it works.

Hope: Set a function that can automatically find max bins given a `q` values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158597/how-to-qcut-with-non-unique-bin-edges

Comment: @user3483203 this is not what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "max" bins?

Comment: @gmds In my example, assumed 12 could work but it can't. So I have to try 11 to test .If failed, then 10, 9 ,8… until it doesn't raise error. The value which doesn't get error is max.