# I have been trying to qcut an array of values into 4 bins. I am getting the error below? How to solve this I am a beginner in Python

Tags: python, pandas, bins

Below is my array data:
`wkx_old['Sales point'].values`

array([ 2,  2,  2,  4,  4,  3,  1,  4,  2,  1,  3,  4,  1,  1,  4,  7,  4,
1,  1,  2,  4,  3,  4,  3,  3,  2,  5,  2,  3,  2,  3,  4,  2, 10,
4,  4,  6,  3,  3,  1,  1,  2,  1,  3,  2,  4,  5,  2,  4,  3,  2,
3,  4,  3,  1,  1,  6,  3,  6,  5,  7,  2,  1,  1,  6,  5,  1,  1,
1,  2,  2,  1,  2,  2,  4,  4,  1,  5,  7,  2,  1,  2,  1,  5,  3,
1,  1,  2,  3,  3,  5,  4,  4,  6,  1,  4,  4,  1,  3,  4,  4,  5,
4,  4,  1,  1,  3,  1,  2,  1,  3,  7,  2,  1,  1,  3,  3,  6,  1,
6,  2,  3,  7,  1])

Trying to compute below code:

`names=['D','C','B','A']`

`wkx_old['Rankings'] = pd.qcut(wkx_old['Sales point'],q=4,labels=names)`

The error I am getting:
ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([ 1.,  1.,  3.,  4., 10.]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg

Comment: please edit the question?

Comment: Check this out, I guess there is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158597/how-to-qcut-with-non-unique-bin-edges/40548606#40548606

Comment: Furthermore your `names` list is too short. With `q=4` you cut into 5 segments (`q` being the number of cuts). Therefore names should be a list of 5 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qcut` is not friendly with duplicated data and will throw an error when it sees a duplicate at splitting point. Imagine you do a `qcut` on `[1]*100`, what is the `50-th` percentile?

You can try `rank(pct=True)` to calculate the actual percentile for the value, then `cut`:

```
wkx_old['Rankings'] = pd.cut(wkx_old['Sales point'].rank(pct=True), 
                             bins=4, labels=names)
```

Output:

```
0      C
1      C
2      C
3      B
4      B
      ..
119    A
120    C
121    C
122    A
123    D
Length: 124, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['D' < 'C' < 'B' < 'A']
```

Comment: thanks, but after making these changes I am still getting the below error-
ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([0.13306452, 0.13306452, 0.5483871 , 0.73790323, 1.        ]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg

Comment: Thanks this really helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

- `qcut` tries to size the windows such that the number of elements are approximately the same for each window. As there are a lot of `1`s in your data, it will try to create this window: `array([ 1.,  1.,  3.,  4., 10.])`, as per the error message. The first two entries are identical, which then leads to the error that you see. To fix this add the parameter `duplicates='drop'` to `qcut`:

```
pd.qcut(wkx_old['Sales point'], q=4, duplicates='drop')
```

- the second problem is that your `names` list is 4 elements long, but you are cutting the data into 5 windows (`q=4` is the number of cuts). To fix this just add another element to the list:

```
names = ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
pd.qcut(wkx_old['Sales point'], q=4, duplicates='drop', labels=names)
```

This should then work.