# How to create quantiles with non-unique bin edges? Python or R

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, quantile

I want to divide my data into quantiles (quintiles to be more specific). However, when using qcut in Pandas or ntile in R, I either get the error that "bin edges must be unique" (qcut) or equal values get assigned to different quintiles (ntile).

Looking at the following data: [1, 8, 2, 1, 8]
I would like the ouput to be:

- 1 assigned to quintile 1
- 8 assigned to quintile 5
- 2 assigned to quintile 3
- 1 assigned to quintile 1 again
- 8 assigned to quintile 5 again

In this specific case the 1s could also be assigned to quintile 2 instead of 1 (depending on definition). It is just important that equal values are assigned to the same quintile.

Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thank you very much for your input!

Some data to use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2011-01-01', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-03','2011-01-01', '2011-01-02', 
'2011-01-03','2011-01-01', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-03', '2011-01-01','2011-01-02', '2011-01-03',
'2011-01-01', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-03'], 'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E'], 
'Value':[1, 3, 2, 8, 6, 5, 2, 10, 4, 1, 5, 3, 8, 4, 9]})
```

Code I used in R:

```
df = df %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate(Quint = ntile(Value, 5))
```

This assigned qual values to different bins.

Code I used in Python:

```
df['Quintiles'] = df.groupby(by=["Date"])['Value'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5, labels=["XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL"]))
```

This resulted in the error of bin edges having to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

> In this specific case the 1s could also be assigned to quintile 2 instead of 1 (depending on definition). It is just important that equal values are assigned to the same quintile.

```
cut_rank = lambda x: pd.cut(x.rank(method='min'), 5, labels=["XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL"])
df['Quintiles'] = df.groupby(by=["Date"])['Value'].transform(cut_rank)
```

Output:

```
>>> df[df['Date'] == '2011-01-01']
          Date Name  Value Quintiles
0   2011-01-01    A      1        XS
3   2011-01-01    B      8        XL
6   2011-01-01    C      2         L
9   2011-01-01    D      1        XS
12  2011-01-01    E      8        XL

>>> df
          Date Name  Value Quintiles
0   2011-01-01    A      1        XS
1   2011-01-02    A      3        XS
2   2011-01-03    A      2        XS
3   2011-01-01    B      8        XL
4   2011-01-02    B      6         L
5   2011-01-03    B      5         L
6   2011-01-01    C      2         L
7   2011-01-02    C     10        XL
8   2011-01-03    C      4         M
9   2011-01-01    D      1        XS
10  2011-01-02    D      5         M
11  2011-01-03    D      3         S
12  2011-01-01    E      8        XL
13  2011-01-02    E      4         S
14  2011-01-03    E      9        XL
```

---

**Old answer**

You have to use `rank` with `method='first'` on each group before `qcut`:

```
qcut_rank = lambda x: pd.qcut(x.rank(method='first'), 5, labels=["XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL"])
df['Quintiles'] = df.groupby(by=["Date"])['Value'].transform(qcut_rank)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          Date Name  Value Quintiles
0   2011-01-01    A      1        XS
1   2011-01-02    A      3        XS
2   2011-01-03    A      2        XS
3   2011-01-01    B      8         L
4   2011-01-02    B      6         L
5   2011-01-03    B      5         L
6   2011-01-01    C      2         M
7   2011-01-02    C     10        XL
8   2011-01-03    C      4         M
9   2011-01-01    D      1         S
10  2011-01-02    D      5         M
11  2011-01-03    D      3         S
12  2011-01-01    E      8        XL
13  2011-01-02    E      4         S
14  2011-01-03    E      9        XL
```

All explanation are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40548606/15239951)

Comment: Based on your link in the answer, should this be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @wikikikitiki. At first intention, I closed the answer and I reopened it after because the groupy_transform.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. Equal values are still assigned to different bins. (See 2011-01-01 for example: the first 8 goes to L the second 8 to XL, same for the first 1 going to XS and the second to S). Is there a way for the 8s to both go to XL, then L is skipped as 40% are already assigned, and then both 1s are assigned to S with XS being skipped again in this case? Only if the 5 numbers completely differ from each other I want them to be assigned to different bins. If they are equal they should all go to the same bin.

Comment: @Quack. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: @Corralien Thank you, this is better but is there a way to put 2 into M and the 1s into S? My intuition for the example would be: 40% of the values are in XL (2 out of 5) as the 8s are of equal value. The threshold for L is 80-60% so it will be skipped in this case as 100-60% are already in XL and the next value should go into M (threshold: 60-40%). For the last remaining values (the 1s) they should go into S as S represents 40-20% but they are of equal value. As all values would be assigned then, XS should not appear in the example case.

Comment: I now tried: ```df['Percentile Rank'] = df.groupby('Date').Value.rank(pct = True)``` which almost gets the correct percentiles. However, instead of assigning the 8s to 100%, it assigns them to 90% and the 1s to 30% instead of 40%. The 2 is correctly assigned to 60%.

Comment: Do you always have 5 values to rank and 5 labels?

Comment: @Corralien No, my actual dataset has about 800 observations per period that need to be ranked. 5 labels would be ideal, but you could also combine XS and S to just Small and XL and L to just Large. I now tried ```df['Percentile Rank2'] = df.groupby('Date').Value.rank(method='max', pct = True)``` which seems to assign the groups correctly. Will this hold for large datasets?

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer as it's looking at [numpy's descriptions of percentile interpolation methods](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html), and not applying directly to `pandas`, but in the manual above, you can see the different options for interpolation of the percentiles for a discontinuous dataset.

```
import numpy as np

x =  [1, 8, 2, 1, 8]

discontinuous_methods = ['linear',
                         'lower',
                         'higher',
                         'midpoint',
                         'nearest']

for method in discontinuous_methods:
    n = [f'{np.percentile(x, i, interpolation = method):.2f}' for i in [20, 40, 60, 80]]
    print(f'{method:8s} - {n[0]:3s}, {n[1]:3s}, {n[2]:3s}, {n[3]:3s}')
```

```
linear   - 1.00, 1.60, 4.40, 8.00
lower    - 1.00, 1.00, 2.00, 8.00
higher   - 1.00, 2.00, 8.00, 8.00
midpoint - 1.00, 1.50, 5.00, 8.00
nearest  - 1.00, 2.00, 2.00, 8.00
```